# Trouble with how to create select statement based on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Looking for some directions on what options I should be considering for the following problem of creating a select statement (SQL SERVER) based on conditions:

NOTE: simplifying the actual problem

If I have two tables, each with a field I need to use
EXAMPLE:

```
CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID
PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID
```

I have 2 other tables that hold special product pricing based on these two fields
EXAMPLE:

```
CUSTOMER_PRICING 
***************************************
* CUSTOMER_ID  * PRODUCT_ID  * PRICE  *
*                                     *
*     ABC      *    100      *  5.00  *
***************************************

MARKET_PRICING 
***************************************
* CUSTOMER_ID  * PRODUCT_ID  * PRICE  *
*                                     *
*     ACME      *    200      *  7.00 *
***************************************
```

For every CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID and PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID I want to join CUSTOMER_PRICING and MARKET_PRICING records using a left outer join.  But the conditions are only if

A) the PRICE field is not null

B) and if a CUSTOMER_ID/PRODUCT_ID exists in both, I only want the record from CUSTOMER_PRICE

Something like:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID, P.PRODUCT_ID FROM CUSTOMER C, PRODUCT P 
           WHERE C.CUSTOMER_ID, P.PRODUCT_ID IN 
           (SELECT PRICE FROM CUSTOMER_PRICE WHERE PRICE IS NOT NULL))
ELSE IF EXISTS 
          (SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID, P.PRODUCT_ID FROM CUSTOMER C, PRODUCT P 
           WHERE C.CUSTOMER_ID, P.PRODUCT_ID IN 
           (SELECT PRICE FROM MARKET_PRICE WHERE PRICE IS NOT NULL))
```

***then somehow do a join on these results.....

Any Suggestions?

Comment: What field are you planning on `JOINING` with? Are there more columns that you're not showing?

Comment: I was planning on join on the PRODUCT_ID and CUSTOMER_ID fields.  Really only the CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_ID and PRICE fields are going to be needed.

Comment: Are you essentially trying to get the `PRODUCT_ID`, `CUSTOMER_ID`, and `PRICE` fields from both of these tables as one single result as long as the price isn't `NULL`?

Comment: @Zero21xxx - Yes, with the logic that Customer_Pricing takes priority over Market_pricing if the same customer_id/product_Id record exists in both tables.

Comment: Can there be more than one price for the same pair of `(CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_ID)` in either of these tables? I mean I understand that the same pair can be present in both tables. My question is whether it can occur more than once in one table (either of the two).

Comment: @Andriy M - No, its key constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Creating a view called CMPricing would greatly simplify this situation.

`CREATE VIEW CMPricing
AS

SELECT
t1.CUSTOMER_ID,
t1.PRODUCT_ID,
t1.PRICE AS CUSTOMER_PRICE
t2.PRICE AS MARKET_PRICE

FROM CUSTOMER_PRICING t1
INNER JOIN MARKET_PRICING t2
ON t1.CUSTOMER_ID = t2.CUSTOMER_ID
AND t1.PRODUCT_ID = t2.PRODUCT_ID

WHERE t1.PRICE IS NOT NULL 
AND t2.PRICE IS NOT NULL`
Then you query this view to get what you want.

This view will contain only the data that is common between both **"PRICE" tables** where both **"PRICE" values** are not null. This view in essence does the filtering for you which in turn makes your queries with the other data tables easier to do and understand.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've come up with a solution. I'm sure a SQL expert could come up with something better, but this should get you moving:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID, C.PRODUCT_ID, C.CUSTOMER_PRICE as [PRICE], 1 as [T]
    FROM CUSTOMER_PRICE C WHERE C.CUSTOMER_PRICE IS NOT NULL
    UNION
    SELECT P.CUSTOMER_ID, P.PRODUCT_ID,P.MARKET_PRICE as [PRICE], 2 as [T]
    FROM MARKET_PRICE P WHERE P.MARKET_PRICE IS NOT NULL
)
select CUSTOMER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) PRICE FROM CTE i WHERE i.CUSTOMER_ID = o.CUSTOMER_ID AND i.PRODUCT_ID = o.PRODUCT_ID
        ORDER BY T
    ) as [PRICE]
from CTE o
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID,PRODUCT_ID
```

That will give you a distinct list of Customer IDs, Product IDs, and Prices; favoring the `CUSTOMER_PRICE` price.

*EDIT*
This will only work with SQL databases 2008 and up. It makes use of [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) which are new constructs to 2008.

*UPDATE*
Fixed where clause.

Answer (score 1):

You could join the cross-product of `CUSTOMER` and `PRODUCT` with both `CUSTOMER_PRICING` and `MARKET_PRICING`, filtering out the rows where both `CUSTOMER_PRICING.PRICE` and `MARKET_PRICING.PRICE` are NULL. It might look something like this:

```
SELECT
  c.CUSTOMER_ID,
  p.PRODUCT_ID,
  COALESCE(cp.PRICE, mp.PRICE) AS PRICE
FROM CUSTOMER c
  CROSS JOIN PRODUCT p
  LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER_PRICING cp ON cp.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID AND cp.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID
  LEFT JOIN MARKET_PRICING   mp ON mp.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID AND mp.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE cp.PRICE IS NOT NULL OR mp.PRICE IS NOT NULL
-- Or, put differently:
-- WHERE NOT (cp.PRICE IS NULL AND mp.PRICE IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ORACLE, you should use union to eliminate the duplicate rows and make 2 separate queries.

Comment: Updated question - using SQL Server 2008